# Swift load nested xib

Tags: swift, xib

I am using the xib approach to view controllers and I'm trying to load another xib inside a xib. Is this possible as every documented method I have tried has failed.

I've tried the following: https://medium.com/@brianclouser/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960

And also using the following:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setup()
    view.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
}

func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: identifier, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}
```

The problem I'm having is the infinite loop scenario, no doubt called from required init. In both approaches files owner has been set/unset as the custom class is unset/set. I've also cleaned the project as well as removed derived data. Just wondered if this was possible?

Thanks

Comment: You say "I'm trying to load another xib inside a xib." But is `identifier` the same as the `identifier` of this view's nib? If so, you are trying to load the view and put it inside itself. This would give you the infinite loop; you are loading the _same_ xib inside a xib. Or are these views the same UIView subclass? Hard to tell what's going on, as you have not shown enough code.

Comment: What would be the process? I've created a xib view and then assigned its file owner a class which is of type UIView. Then I hooked up the outlets to the file's owner. I also added in the loadView() code above. When on a "Controller xIb" I have an empty UIView which I've custom classed to the newly created xib. This crashes!